# Stage declared on Jenkinsfile not being executed when a merge to master occurs

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I want the following `Jenkinsfile` stage

```
    stage('building & pushing latest image') {
      when {
        allOf {
          changeset 'my-directory/**/*'
          expression {
              env.BRANCH_NAME == 'master'
          }
        }
      }
```

to be executed when **both** conditions are valid:

a) there are changes in/under `my-directory`

b) there is a merge to `master`. ideally I would like this to be executed when

1. there is a pull request targeting master
2. after the merge occurs.

However for some reason the above did not run after a merge I performed.

Is something wrong with my `when` condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `branch 'master';` instead of your expression block.

EDIT: I'd also suggest making sure your SCM doesn't need an additional web hook integration created. I had to do this for an older version of Bitbucket Server.